# Check for consecutive elements in vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, indicator

I have a vector of K elements and I need to check if it contains a precise subset of 2 consecutive elements.

Assume K = 6

```
vec = c(4,4,3,1,2,2)
```

How can I get an indicator that checks for the subset (4,2) as consecutive elements? Should return FALSE in this example while (3,1) should return TRUE.

Answer (score 3):

One another approach could be:

```
grepl("42", paste(vec, collapse = ""))

[1] FALSE

grepl("31", paste(vec, collapse = ""))

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Use rollapply with the identical function.

```
library(zoo)

vec <- c(4,4,3,1,2,2)
x <- c(4, 2)
any(rollapply(vec, length(x), identical, x))
## [1] FALSE

x <- c(3, 1)
any(rollapply(vec, length(x), identical, x))
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** Create strings out of vec and x and use grepl:

```
x <- c(4, 2)
grepl(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", toString(x)), toString(vec))
## [1] FALSE

x <- c(3, 1)
grepl(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", toString(x)), toString(vec))
## [1] TRUE
```

**3)** If x always has two elements then:

```
x <- c(4, 2)
any(head(vec, -1) == x[1] & tail(vec, -1) == x[2])
## [1] FALSE

x <- c(3, 1)
any(head(vec, -1) == x[1] & tail(vec, -1) == x[2])
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you have more than 2 elements to check, this might be worthwhile:

```
vec <-= c(4,4,3,1,2,2)
chk <- c(3, 1)

as.logical(length(Reduce(intersect, lapply(seq_along(chk), function(x) which(chk[x] == lead(vec, x - 1))))))
# [1] TRUE

chk <- c(4, 1)
as.logical(length(Reduce(intersect, lapply(seq_along(chk), function(x) which(chk[x] == lead(vec, x - 1))))))
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
find_subsequence = function (vec, needle) {
    sub_idx = seq_along(needle) - 1L
    Filter(
        function (i) all(needle == vec[sub_idx + i]),
        seq_len(length(vec) - length(needle) + 1L)
    )
}
```

```
find_subsequence(vec, c(3, 1))
# [1] 4
find_subsequence(vec, c(4, 2))
# integer(0)
```